# How to skip past an "=" then capture all comma-delimited words

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am doing this now with Instr/Split but have found regex in general to be much faster (this is an inner loop with 100K+ tests per run).

The general form is:

```
word0 = word1, word2, word3...
```

There are one or more words to the right of `=`. A word is defined as `[\w.-]+`. I need to allow for whitespace at any point as well. The `=` is required.

I want to return just *word1*, *word2* and *word3* in the Matches collection.

The `=` is what has me stumped. I either get one match or none depending on the pattern.

Here is some test code. Change `RE.Pattern` on line 17 to test.

```
Option Explicit

Test1 "word1, word2",""
Test1 " word0 = word1, word.2  , word3.qrs_t-1", "word1 word.2 word3.qrs_t-1"
Test1 "word0=word1", "word1"

WScript.Quit

Sub Test1(TestString, CorrectOutput)

    Dim RE, Matches, Answer
    Dim i, j

    Set RE     = New RegExp
    RE.Global  = True

    RE.Pattern = "=([\w.-]+)"

    Set Matches = RE.Execute(TestString)

    Answer =  "Input:  " & vbTab & TestString & vbLf
    Answer = Answer & "Correct:" & vbTab & CorrectOutput & vbLf

    Answer = Answer &  "Actual: " & vbTab

    For i = 0 To Matches.Count -1
        If i > 0 Then
            Answer = Answer & " "
        End If
        Answer = Answer & Matches(i).value
    Next

    MsgBox Answer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Give this a try, it'll:

- require a value before the equals sign
- require an equals sign
- require at least 1 value after the equals sign
- return each of the 1 to 3 comma delimited chunks of text
- trim spaces off all returned values

`(?:^\s*?(\b[^=]*?\b)(?:\s{0,}[=]\s{0,}))(?:(['"]?)(\b[^,]*\b)\2\s*?)(?:$|(?:[,]\s*?(['"]?)(\b[^,]*\b)\4\s*?)(?:$|[,]\s*?(['"]?)(\b[^,]*\b)\6\s*?$))`

[image]
(Right click the image and select view in new tab or new window for full size)

## Groups

- group 0 matches the full string if it's valid
- groups 1-7

  1. value before the equals sign
  2. Quote delimiter if there was one for value 1
  3. first value in the list of values
  4. Quote delimiter if there was one for value 2
  5. second value in the list of values
  6. Quote delimiter if there was on for value 3
  7. third value in the list of values

## VB.NET Code Example to demonstrate the that the regex works

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(?:^\s*?(\b[^=]*?\b)(?:\s{0,}[=]\s{0,}))(?:(['"]?)(\b[^,]*\b)\2\s*?)(?:$|(?:[,]\s*?(['"]?)(\b[^,]*\b)\4\s*?)(?:$|[,]\s*?(['"]?)(\b[^,]*\b)\6\s*?$))",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  word0 = word1, word.2  , word3.qrs_t-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => word0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => word1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => word.2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => word3.qrs_t-1
        )

)
```

Comment: The OP is using VBScript, not VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression to extract the the substring with the wordlist from the input string:

```
str = "..."

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^.*?=((?:[^,]+)(?:,[^,]+)*)"
re.Global  = True

Set m = re.Execute(str)
```

Then use a second expression to remove the separating commas and mangle the whitespace:

```
Set re2 = New RegExp
re2.Pattern = "\s*,\s*"
re2.Global  = True

wordlist = ""
If m.Count > 0 Then
  wordlist = Trim(re2.Replace(m(0).SubMatches(0), " "))
End If

WScript.Echo wordlist
```